# How to prevent OnDemandConnRouteHelper.dll from being loaded and unloaded every http request?

Tags: winapi, serverxmlhttp

Calling [`IServerXmlHttpRequest.Open`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/desktop/ms763809(v=vs.85)):

```
var http = (IServerXMLHTTPRequest2) new CreateComObject(CLASS_ServerXMLHTTP60);
http.Open("GET", "https://thepiratebay.org/description.php?id=54783221", false, "mhalifa", "hunter2");
```

causes the library [**OnDemandConnRouteHelper.dll**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/ondemandconnroutehelper/nf-ondemandconnroutehelper-ondemandgetroutinghint) to be loaded and unloaded every time:

```
| Time               | Operation                 | Path                                            | Result                        |
|--------------------|---------------------------|-------------------------------------------------|-------------------------------|
| 3:08:29.0705523 PM | CreateFile                | C:\WINDOWS\SysWOW64\OnDemandConnRouteHelper.dll | SUCCESS                       |
| 3:08:29.0705941 PM | QueryBasicInformationFile | C:\WINDOWS\SysWOW64\OnDemandConnRouteHelper.dll | SUCCESS                       |
| 3:08:29.0706149 PM | CloseFile                 | C:\WINDOWS\SysWOW64\OnDemandConnRouteHelper.dll | SUCCESS                       |
| 3:08:29.0708557 PM | CreateFile                | C:\WINDOWS\SysWOW64\OnDemandConnRouteHelper.dll | SUCCESS                       |
| 3:08:29.0709287 PM | CreateFileMapping         | C:\WINDOWS\SysWOW64\OnDemandConnRouteHelper.dll | FILE LOCKED WITH ONLY READERS |
| 3:08:29.0712518 PM | CreateFileMapping         | C:\WINDOWS\SysWOW64\OnDemandConnRouteHelper.dll | SUCCESS                       |
| 3:08:29.0714096 PM | Load Image                | C:\WINDOWS\SysWOW64\OnDemandConnRouteHelper.dll | SUCCESS                       |
| 3:08:29.0714328 PM | QueryNameInformationFile  | C:\WINDOWS\SysWOW64\OnDemandConnRouteHelper.dll | SUCCESS                       |
| 3:08:29.0717643 PM | CreateFile                | C:\WINDOWS\SysWOW64\OnDemandConnRouteHelper.dll | SUCCESS                       |
| 3:08:29.0807774 PM | CloseFile                 | C:\WINDOWS\SysWOW64\OnDemandConnRouteHelper.dll | SUCCESS                       |
| 3:08:29.0810143 PM | QueryNameInformationFile  | C:\WINDOWS\SysWOW64\OnDemandConnRouteHelper.dll | SUCCESS                       |
```

As you can see, this excursion adds `10.462 ms` to my http request.

When the entire request is ~30 ms, this extra load and unload of a dll ***every time*** increases the operation times by 50%.

And cuts my throughput from 50 requests/sec → 33 requests/sec.

### Enough of the motivation for the question, and on to the questions

- what is **OnDemandConnRouteHelper.dll**
- is there something i can do to my request to not require help?
- can i ask the ServerXMLHTTPRequest object to not use the helper?
- can i convince ServerXMLHTTPRequest to keep the dll loaded in my process forever?

In other words: i want my 50% back - how do i get it?

### Conn Route Helper

I don't know what this dll does, but the only useful function is documented to:

> The OnDemandGetRoutingHint function looks up a destination in the Route Request cache and, if a match is found, return the corresponding Interface ID.

Which sounds interesting and all. But if you immediately unload the dll, you throw away the cache with it - thus destroying any usefulness of the cache.

Comment: *can i convince ServerXMLHTTPRequest to keep the dll loaded in my process forever?* you can by self call `LoadLibraryW(L"OnDemandConnRouteHelper")` - as result this dll will be loaded once and never unloaded

Comment: *(that was the hack i was using. shhhhh)*

Comment: With all due respect, if you're aiming at servicing 50 requests/sec, performance clearly isn't a design goal, so why do you even care about 50% more or less? I mean, I'm a huge proponent of resource efficiency, but dude, 50 requests/sec... Are you running this on a Zilog Z80, clocked at 4 MHz? If so, are you planning to actually render the DVD Rip of [*"Young Tight Latinas 1, 2, 3, 4"*](https://thepiratebay.org/description.php?id=54783221) on that device as well? That may not pan out as intended...

Comment: They never said they were targeting 50 requests/sec. That number comes from the empirical data. Each request is currently taking approx. 30ms to complete which is approx. 33 requests/sec. 10ms of that time is spent loading and unloading this DLL, so a single thread issuing a single request at a time could issue approx. 50 requests/sec if that 10ms wasn't wasted loading and unloading that DLL for every single request. Obviously if they want to increase throughput further than that they will need to issue multiple requests in parallel, but that's beside the point.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not an answer, but a workaround is to load the library once manually.

There is no need in Windows to unload a DLL before program exit - the DLLs will be unloaded when the process is torn down by Windows.

So there's no harm in calling:

- `LoadLibrary('OnDemandConnRouteHelper');`

In fact, there's no harm in calling it multiple times.

Just don't call `UnloadLibrary`; because then it has to be loaded again.